# How to query list of permitted children from partitioned group?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE relationships_group (
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    position TEXT NOT NULL,
    sub_group TEXT NOT NULL,
    big_group TEXT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO relationships_group (username, position, sub_group, big_group) VALUES
    ('A', '1', 'S1', 'G1'),
    ('B', '2', 'S1', 'G1'),
    ('C', '3', 'S1', 'G1'),
    ('D', '4', 'S1', 'G1'),

    ('E', '1', 'S2', 'G1'),
    ('F', '2', 'S2', 'G1'),
    ('C', '3', 'S2', 'G1'),
    ('D', '4', 'S2', 'G1'),

    ('D', '1', 'S3', 'G2'),
    ('C', '2', 'S3', 'G2'),
    ('B', '3', 'S3', 'G2'),
    ('A', '4', 'S3', 'G2'),

    ('D', '1', 'S4', 'G2'),
    ('C', '2', 'S4', 'G2'),
    ('F', '3', 'S4', 'G2'),
    ('E', '4', 'S4', 'G2');
```

I want to output the following table

```
  username  big_group   permitted
    'A'      'G1'       [A]
    'B'      'G1'       [A B]
    'C'      'G1'       [A B C E F]
    'D'      'G1'       [A B C D E F]
    'E'      'G1'       [E]
    'F'      'G1'       [E F]
    'A'      'G2'       [A B C D]
    'B'      'G2'       [B C D]
    'C'      'G2'       [C D]
    'D'      'G2'       [D]
    'E'      'G2'       [C D F E]
    'F'      'G2'       [C D F]
```

Basically higher position is allowed to access  the lower position. The list is generated using sub groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a window function to handle the `position` ordering, then combine the resulting sublists by `big_group`:

```
with perms as (
  select username, big_group,
         array_agg(username)
           over (partition by big_group, sub_group
                     order by position) as objs
    from relationships_group
)
select username, big_group,
       array_agg(distinct o order by o) as permitted
  from perms
 cross join lateral unnest(objs) as u(o)
 group by username, big_group
 order by big_group, username;
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5DUJRYuGCK3tPPnpKNZseD/0)

This can also be done using joins without window functions:

```
select username, big_group, 
       array_agg(distinct obj order by obj) as permitted
  from (select a.username, a.big_group, b.username as obj
          from relationships_group a
               join relationships_group b
                 on b.position <= a.position
                and b.big_group = a.big_group
                and b.sub_group = a.sub_group) x
 group by username, big_group
 order by big_group, username;
```

[Second fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7f39b/5)

Comment: Wow this is the first time I see `join on ... <=....` fantastic :) Thank you for the idea!